# How do I sum the values in an array of maps in jq?

Tags: json, sum, key, jq

Given a JSON stream of the following form:

```
{ "a": 10, "b": 11 } { "a": 20, "b": 21 } { "a": 30, "b": 31 }
```

I would like to sum the values in each of the objects and output a single object, namely:

```
{ "a": 60, "b": 63 }
```

I'm guessing this will probably require flattening the above list of objects into a an array of `[name, value]` pairs and then summing the values using `reduce` but the documentation of the syntax for using `reduce` is woeful.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unless your jq has `inputs`, you will have to slurp the objects up using the `-s` flag.  Then  you'll have to do a fair amount of manipulation:

1. Each of the objects needs to be mapped out to key/value pairs
2. Flatten the pairs to a single array
3. Group up the pairs by key
4. Map out each group accumulating the values to a single key/value pair
5. Map the pairs back to an object

```
map(to_entries)
    | add
    | group_by(.key)
    | map({
          key: .[0].key,
          value: map(.value) | add
      })
    | from_entries
```

---

With jq 1.5, this could be greatly improved:  You can do away with slurping and just read the `inputs` directly.

```
$ jq -n '
reduce (inputs | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .[$key] += $value)
' input.json
```

Since we're simply accumulating all the values in each of the objects, it'll be easier to just run through the key/value pairs of all the inputs, and add them all up.

Comment: Ah, the group_by is what I was missing, I'd overlooked it in the documentation. Also, I got the tool producing the source data to output as a single JSON stream so '-s' wasn't needed. The only other tweak I made was to use 'flatten' instead of 'add'. Thanks for the answer, it was spot on :-)

Comment: Reduce is awesome! I'm struggling with how it might support 2 methods (sum and avg for isntance)

It doesnt like sem-colons, commas seem to run the last manipulation only

reduce .usage."os:linux"[] as $item (
{"credits":0,"minutes":0}; 
."credits" += $item.credits;
."minutes" += $item.amount /1000/60
)

Comment: @Eddie: semicolons are used for separating parameters to function calls. The way you're using it there, it should be pipes and it would work like you would expect.

Comment: Shouldn't `jq -s 'reduce (.[] | to_entries[]) ...` work just as well as `jq -n 'reduce (inputs | to_entries[]) ...`?  I'm missing the need for the mapping, `group_by`, etc.

Or does lacking `inputs` imply a jq version lacking other constructs in the `-n` example?

Comment: For those working with a stream already in jq, make sure to use `[ ... ]` around the stream before `map(to_entries)` to convert it to an array.

Comment: @ggorlen, if you're going to stream it, may as well write it as `[... | to_entries]`

Comment: Finally found a compelling use for reduce! Thanks @JeffMercado. I was trying to add a total key in the same iteration using the group_by method and getting very confused. With reduce it's trivial to manipulate arbitrary keys on each iteration.

Answer (score 19):

I faced the same question when listing all artifacts from GitHub (see [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/actions/artifacts/#list-artifacts-for-a-repository) for details) and want to sum their size.

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/artifacts \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
     -H "Authorization:  token <your_pat_here>" \
     | jq '.artifacts | map(.size_in_bytes) | add'
```

Input:

```
{
  "total_count": 3,
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "id": 0000001,
      "node_id": "MDg6QXJ0aWZhY3QyNzUxNjI1",
      "name": "artifact-1",
      "size_in_bytes": 1,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/artifacts/2751625",
      "archive_download_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/artifacts/2751625/zip",
      "expired": false,
      "created_at": "2020-03-10T18:21:23Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-03-10T18:21:24Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 0000002,
      "node_id": "MDg6QXJ0aWZhY3QyNzUxNjI0",
      "name": "artifact-2",
      "size_in_bytes": 2,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/artifacts/2751624",
      "archive_download_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/artifacts/2751624/zip",
      "expired": false,
      "created_at": "2020-03-10T18:21:23Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-03-10T18:21:24Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 0000003,
      "node_id": "MDg6QXJ0aWZhY3QyNzI3NTk1",
      "name": "artifact-3",
      "size_in_bytes": 3,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/docker/mercury-ui/actions/artifacts/2727595",
      "archive_download_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/actions/artifacts/2727595/zip",
      "expired": false,
      "created_at": "2020-03-10T08:46:08Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-03-10T08:46:09Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: Use the -`s` flag to make it work: `jq -s '.artifacts | map(.size_in_bytes) | add'`.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach, which illustrates the power of jq quite nicely, is to use a filter named "sum" defined as follows:

```
def sum(f): reduce .[] as $row (0; . + ($row|f) );
```

To solve the particular problem at hand, one could then use the `-s` (--slurp) option as mentioned above, together with the expression:

```
{"a": sum(.a), "b": sum(.b) }  # (2)
```

The expression labeled (2) only computes the two specified sums, but it is easy to generalize, e.g. as follows:

```
# Produce an object with the same keys as the first object in the 
# input array, but with values equal to the sum of the corresponding
# values in all the objects.
def sumByKey:
  . as $in
  | reduce (.[0] | keys)[] as $key
    ( {}; . + {($key): ($in | sum(.[$key]))})
;
```