# JQ: Why does summing numbers from field in JSON stream not include first number in sum?

Tags: bash, stream, sum, jq, reduce

I have a list of credit card transactions. I would like to sum the Amount from the stream of JSON transactions. Each object contains data for 1 transaction. I use JQ to process JSON.

I have referenced this question: [How do I sum the values in an array of maps in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484534/how-do-i-sum-the-values-in-an-array-of-maps-in-jq)

However after implementing the solution described in the question.

```sh
jq -n '
reduce (inputs | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .[$key] += $value)
' input.json
```

I noticed that the first number is not included in the addition. Below find sample file, output of command, and expected result

### Sample File CC Transactions "jqAdditionSample.json"

```
{
  "Originating Account Number": "####-####-####-0000",
  "Cardholder Name": "NAME ON CARD",
  "Merchant Name": "VENDOR NAME",
  "Amount": 342.75,
  "MCC Description": "Computer Software"
}
{
  "Originating Account Number": "####-####-####-0000",
  "Cardholder Name": "NAME ON CARD",
  "Merchant Name": "VENDOR NAME",
  "Amount": 492.71,
  "MCC Description": "Computer Software"
}
{
  "Originating Account Number": "####-####-####-0000",
  "Cardholder Name": "NAME ON CARD",
  "Merchant Name": "VENDOR NAME",
  "Amount": 573,
  "MCC Description": "Computer Software"
}
```

### Expected Actual Total

Add the Amounts manually to find total 342.75+492.71+573=1408.46

### Run the command

```sh
cat ~/Desktop/jqAdditionSample.json | \
  jq 'reduce (inputs | to_entries[]) as {$key,$value} ({}; .[$key] += $value)'
```

Result:

```
{
  "Originating Account Number": "####-####-####-0000####-####-####-0000",
  "Cardholder Name": "NAME ON CARDNAME ON CARD",
  "Merchant Name": "VENDOR NAMEVENDOR NAME",
  "Amount": 1065.71,
  "MCC Description": "Computer SoftwareComputer Software"
}
```

### Note Discrepancy

The output 1065.71 adds sums all numbers except the first number. We can verify by subtracting 342.75 from expected value 1408.46. I want it to sum all numbers

In fact, no data from the first object is included in the sum.

### Where I need help

Is there a way to make JQ sum all numbers from a field in a stream, am I doing something wrong?

Is there an easier method to sum all numbers for a field in JSON stream where I am taking the hard route?

Comment: You aren't using `-n` in the "run the command" section, even though it's present in the "solution described in the question" code you quote. It's critical if you don't want your first entry to be consumed.

Comment: BTW, when you use backticks instead of four-space indents to format code (or structured data like JSON), you defeat Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting. Please use code sections when quoting a line or more of code or structured (syntax-highlightable) data.

Comment: ...as another aside, `cat file | jq ...` is much better written as `<file jq ...` or `jq ... file`, which give `jq` a direct handle on the input file itself. That's not a *huge* deal for `jq`, but for commands that benefit from being able to split into threads that read from the file in parallel, or seek to the end directly, or test the size without reading it all, giving a FIFO instead of a real file handle can make an orders-of-magnitude difference in efficiency. (Compare performance of `tail` or GNU `sort` or `wc -c` on multi-GB files when reading from `cat` vs given direct handles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you're using `inputs`. According to the documentation, `inputs` "outputs all remaining inputs, one by one". Fine, but note the "remaining" part. By the time your code is run, the *first* input has already been read into `.`, so `inputs` returns all of the records *except* that one. The simple fix is to use the `-n` option to jq, which runs the filter once, with the `null` value in `.`. This leaves *all* of the records available for reading by `inputs`, which makes your code work correctly.

Comment: Ah interesting. I had always used `-n` to construct JSON objects from scratch while providing no input, an oversight indeed. That's useful that it can also be used to run the first iteration of a filter as well. Thank you